# Visual C++ Win32 api code to intercept a certain keystroke

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

My windows 10 is typing the character minus(-) every few minutes, I've checked it and found that it is not a problem of my keyboard. Now I want to write a program running in background that intercepts and removes the unwanted character, whenever I'm doing some serious work ? How to do this using win32 api ? (This way I'll also get to learn Win32 API.)

Tools Using -

- Visual Studio C++ 2010 express-
- Win 10 sdk.

I'm following this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/learnwin32/keyboard-input

Comment: Visual Studio C++ 2010 and the Windows 10 SDK are not compatible. Is there any reason you are still using Visual Studio C++ 2010 express?

Comment: Use the function `SetWindowsHookEx`,  this is its example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-hooks

Comment: @Axalo no there is no specific reason, I can move to newer version, which one will u suggest for win sdk 10 devlopment ??

Comment: What happens if you need to type that character? I don't think you have diagnosed the problem properly. In normal operation, the system doesn't just toss in keyboard events for nothing.

Comment: @David Heffernan There shall be many ways I can implement selective typing e.g double tapping, long press or key combination.... Regarding diagnosis of my system I can say I have done preliminary diagnosis and my motive of going this way is partially due to the   new learning opportunity I'll have....

Comment: Now let's be honest here. The reason you are going for this 'solution' is, that you failed to identify the piece of malware you installed in your system, that's responsible for the observed behavior. If learning were the true motivation, then go with learning how to diagnose this issue.

Comment: @IInspectable Okay I'll try harder in that direction too, but to be honest I genuinely think learning is in both ways.

Comment: Does this issue still happen when your keyboard is disconnected?

Comment: I haven't checked after disconnecting keyboard but I have tried on 2 different keyboards. Issue remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_KEYUP) && lParam != NULL)
    {
        if (((LPKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->vkCode == VK_OEM_MINUS)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    HHOOK hHook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"hooking", L"", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_SYSTEMMODAL);
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    return 0;
}
```

Build and run this program, you will find that you can not type '-' to the screen anywhere.

If it does not work for some target process, run this program with admin privilege.

Comment: [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: sorry, I do not understand

Comment: In `wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_KEYUP && lParam != NULL`, first the `&&` operator is evaluated, then `||`. Use parenthesis to override operator precedence: `(wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_KEYUP) && lParam != NULL`

Comment: I see, that's my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: That's *one* of the numerous issues with the code. Other than that, it fails to implement the documented [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx). I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to explain `return 112;` either. And if you can, it's unclear why you chose `112` over, say, `1` or `TRUE`.

Comment: I changed it to 1. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is still wrong, as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: But this code is working fine, I got rid of the annoying issue. @shilyx could you please refer all the related documentation of the above code? Also if possible please refer good tutorials for win32 api development.

Comment: @hum: It gets rid of the *"annoying issue"* by needlessly introducing new issues. The documentation tells you, how to *properly* implement a hook procedure. This proposed answer doesn't. If you are looking to really learn the Windows API, get a copy of Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X). There is no substitute.